# Scala Play Framework getting user's ip address

Tags: scala, playframework

I have seen this asked before, but I haven't been able to use those answers to get the IP address of the user.

in PHP it would be this:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: what is exact problem? how do you tried to employ that answers and what problems you have stumbled upon?

Comment: yes and none of the answers work

Comment: request.remoteAddress does not work? Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: do I need to import any dependencies?

Answer (score 8):

If you need to access this information within an action:

```
Action { request =>
    val address = request.remoteAddress;
    ...
}
```

If you need the access somewhere else, note that you can use implicit:

```
Action { implicit request => ... }
myMethod(implicit request: Request) { ... }
```

And you can always fall back to just passing the request around.